# Saving a date field value into physical file

Tags: database, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I have a date field which accepts system date in AS400

Display file contains a date field by *DATE

I have a physical file that has a date column.When i try saving the other fields of my screen onto this physical file,i would also like to save this system date.

But i am unable to add a field name to this inbuilt Date function.

How else can i have a date field in my display screen that will automatically accept system date and have format in DD/mm/yy format for input but internally in database it must save it as yy/mm/dd.

For the purpose of having this internal conversion in my database of date format,i have initialized a date field named "date" of length 6,Packed decimal,0 decimal position.

Please guide how to save system date from screen in this format into the physical file.

Reedited:
I have a PF of grade received date defines as follows.(Its DDS)

```
   0004.00      A            GRCVDT         6P 0
```

I refrain to use 'L' data type for date as i want to perform date conversion as i have above explained.

Comment: I'm afraid there is confusion here. Utilization of an L data type frees_you_from having to _convert_ dates from one format to another! Dates that are stored as dates can be represented in any format (output) and populated from any format (input). e.g. mydate = %date('31.07.2012', *EUR) or DUMMY = %Char(mydate, *USA) even though mydate is defined as a *ISO (or any other) format by default.  The system knows what do to _because_ it is a date field.

Comment: @Dennis I actually want to perform some computations on the date field  like given a TO and FROM value it must return records of that Period.Hence the conversion.

Comment: You can do this with date fields, or with numeric ones.  You want to keep converting to/from YYYYMMDD, that's up to you.  I'm just saying that it's not been necessary to do that for over 18 years.  Date fields have been around that long ((!!!)).  The only problem is lack of adoption (or perhaps lack of education).  Scott Klement said (paraphrasing) it's easier to grow a new programmer from scratch than to get an existing one to use the "newer" (meaning, in the last 15 years or so) features.  Guess he was right.

Answer (score 3):

On a display file, *DATE is output-only.  It cannot be read by a program.

It sounds like the database table has a decimal field called DATE; not a date field called DATE.  Using a date data type will make date manipulation so much easier - see Dennis' answer for advice on that.  If it is impossible to use a date data type, and you must use a decimal data type to hold the date value, look at the RPG [TIME](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzasd/sc0925081020.htm) operation code.  That will allow you to extract the current system date into a program variable.  The exact format the date will be returned depends on your job date format setting. (WRKJOB to see that).  You can use a data structure and a series of EVAL statements to rearrange the date elements if you need to.

EDIT Code sample to convert EUR to YYMMDD

```
 d eur             ds                  qualified
 d ddmmyy                         6s 0
 d  dd                            2s 0 overlay(ddmmyy: 1)
 d  mm                            2s 0 overlay(ddmmyy: 3)
 d  yy                            2s 0 overlay(ddmmyy: 5)

 d ymd             ds                  qualified
 d yymmdd                         6s 0
 d  yy                            2s 0 overlay(yymmdd: 1)
 d  mm                            2s 0 overlay(yymmdd: 3)
 d  dd                            2s 0 overlay(yymmdd: 5)

 c/free
   eur.ddmmyy = 020812;
   ymd.yy = eur.yy;
   ymd.mm = eur.mm;
   ymd.dd = eur.dd;
   dsply ymd.yymmdd;
   *inlr = *on;
  /end-free
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that info.But can u still share some idea how i can actually perform a type conversion of date.Lets say i accept the date form a display file in *EUR format through decimal data type declaration.Now i want to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd format as i want to fetch data by subtracting the days part of this value(hence the conversion of types).Appreciate ur help

Comment: @techie - Please see also the comment I added to your original post.

Comment: And if you want to get "fancy", you could say `EVAL-CORR ymd=eur;` which would move the 3 small fields according to matching names.

Comment: @BuckCalabro On my display file what should i refer my date field as.Also is this to be included in the PF that holds my initialization for date.Since m very naive on this platform would appreciate ur guidance.

Comment: The answer to 'how do I define my display file date field' depends entirely on how the rest of your system defines date fields.  Imagine your end user's surprise if she types 6 digits into every date field in the system and then comes to yours and must type 8 Aug 2012, or 2012-08-08?  Make the date field the same as the rest of the system, probably the same as GRCVDT in your PF.

Answer (score 1):

Is this file created via DDS or SQL?  If DDS, then please add the field of your choice to the DDS specs, and specify a Data Type of L:

```
     A            MYDATE          L
```

Then use CHGPF, specifying the source file and member name; the system will add the new column.

```
CHGPF FILE(MYLIB/MYFILE)           
      SRCFILE(MYSRCLIB/MYSOURCE)      
      SRCMBR(MY_MBR)
```

Even if your file is DDS described, you could add the date column by using an SQL statement like:
   alter table mytable add column mydate date not null default

(But of course, if you do that, you cannot recreate the file from DDS anymore without losing the new column)

Then in your program, just before the WRITE to the data, do:
    mydate = %date

There are many assumptions here: you are using ILE, you know how to modify and recompile the program, you are using free form or can translate the  "variable = value" syntax above, ...)

There are also other ways to get the system date into a file without your program having to do anything special; we actually need to know more about the application in order to help much beyond this high-level advice.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Issue doesnt lie on how i can go about making the changes or compilation but its with the logic of performing date type conversion.I have defined my date field in PF as shown in Reedits,i have d display file where i defined date as sys date by *DATE so i am unable to fetch that value.Is there any way of performing calculation with that variable?

Comment: Well, if you are trying to get system date, why must you "fetch" it from the display? System date is now, not something that happens to be on a display, which could technically be months old. %DATE (for a true date value) or UDATE (or UMONTH, UDAY, UYEAR used however you like) may help you out. Or TIME operation code, as pointed out by @buckcalabro, in his answer below.